# Why are my Python arguments not unpacking?

Tags: python, argument-passing

I am a bit confused about [unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).  I am trying to make an XSL-FO file programatically and therefore need to insert a variable number of elements at some point in the file.  Of course I could do this other ways (XML/XSLT, other XML methods, etc) but I'd like to know why this isn't working because maybe my basic knowledge of Python is a bit rusty.  Right by "RIGHT HERE" I'm trying to insert my column_elms list as a variable number of parameters.  Note that this does not take a list, and that if I copy what's on the next line (`E("table-column...),` over and over it does, in fact, produce the desired output (multiple `table-column` elements.  But with unpacking this, it just gives me one `table-column` element no matter what.  What's going on‽‽‽

```
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker
from lxml import etree as ET  
COLUMNS = 8
E = ElementMaker(namespace='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format',
                 nsmap={'fo':"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"})
column_elms = [E("table-column",{"column-width":"41mm"})] * COLUMNS
root = E("root",
         E("layout-master-set",
           E("simple-page-master",
             {"master-name":"label-sheet",
                "margin-left":"5mm",
                "margin-right":"5mm",
                "margin-top":"14mm",
                "margin-bottom":"14mm"},
             E("region-body"))),
         E("page-sequence",
           {"master-reference":"label-sheet"},
             E("flow", {"flow-name":"xsl-region-body"},
                E("table", *column_elms # **RIGHT HERE**
                                        # E("table-column",{"column-width":"41mm"}),
                    ))))
```

Comment: An untested hunch: try replacing `column_elms = [E("table-column",{"column-width":"41mm"})] * COLUMNS` with `column_elms = [E("table-column", {"column-width":"41mm"}) for _ in range(COLUMNS)]`?

Comment: @Dougal: Tested, it works. (My guess is that it turns into a set or a dictionary at some point, which means duplicate instances of children will count only once). You should post as an answer.

Comment: @Dougal - that actually did work, thanks.  It turns out multiplying them resulted in the exact same elements (at the same addresses).  Please answer it and I'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a list with `COLUMNS` copies of the *same* object:

```
column_elms = [E("table-column",{"column-width":"41mm"})] * COLUMNS
```

The above code does not call `E()` 8 times, it call it *once* then puts 8 references in the list.

It's as if you ran:

```
column_elms = []
tcolumn = E("table-column",{"column-width":"41mm"})
for i in range(COLUMNS):
    column_elms.append(tcolumn)
```

Use a list comprehension instead:

```
column_elms = [E("table-column",{"column-width":"41mm"}) for _ in xrange(COLUMNS)]
```

which would evaluate the `E(..)` expression for each run through the loop.